# How to select single row in join?

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

```
SELECT 
    MYSCHEME.C.ID as CELLID, 
    MYSCHEME.C.NUM as CELLNUM, 
    MYSCHEME.C.UND_ID as U_ID, 
    MYSCHEME.U.SERIAL as SERIAL, 
    MYSCHEME.U.AMS_NETID as AMSID,
    MYSCHEME.U.IP_ADDRESS as IP_ADDRESS,
    MYSCHEME.U.MAC_ADDRESS as MAC_ADDRESS,
    MYSCHEME.IDARESULTS.ID as IDAID
    FROM 
    MYSCHEME.C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MYSCHEME.U ON MYSCHEME.C.U_ID = MYSCHEME.U.ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MYSCHEME.IDARESULTS ON MYSCHEME.C.ID = MYSCHEME.IDARESULTS.CELLID
    WHERE 
    MYSCHEME.C.SA = 1;
```

Here `IDARESULTS` table has column `ACTION_DATE` which is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

I need to modify above query, so for `LEFT OUTER JOIN MYSCHEME.IDARESULTS ON MYSCHEME.C.ID = MYSCHEME.IDARESULTS.CELLID` returns only 1 record, which has recent timestamp. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN and WHERE MYSCHEME.U.ID IS NOT NULL?

Comment: do you try use TOP 1 and ORDER BY Timestamp Field DESC ?

Comment: @jarlh: sorry you are right, it doesn't make sense, I fixed it.

Comment: @Chanom First: I am not sure where to put this ORDER BY

Comment: @ChanomFirst the question is about oracle not sql-server. top 1 is sql-server not oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use KEEP DENSE_RANK LAST to get the ID for the newest timestamp.

With a sub-query:

```
select 
   c.id as cellid, 
   c.num as cellnum, 
   c.und_id as u_id, 
   u.serial as serial, 
   u.ams_netid as amsid,
   u.ip_address as ip_address,
   u.mac_address as mac_address,
   (
     select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by created_timestamp) 
     from idaresults ida 
     where ida.cellid = c.id
   ) as idaid
from myscheme.c
left outer join myscheme.u on c.u_id = u.id 
where c.sa = 1;
```

Or with a join:

```
select 
   c.id as cellid, 
   c.num as cellnum, 
   c.und_id as u_id, 
   u.serial as serial, 
   u.ams_netid as amsid,
   u.ip_address as ip_address,
   u.mac_address as mac_address,
   ida.id as idaid
from myscheme.c
left outer join myscheme.u on c.u_id = u.id 
left outer join
(
  select cellid, max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by created_timestamp) as id
  from idaresults
  group by cellid
) ida on ida.cellid = c.id
where c.sa = 1;
```

Comment: What if I want to query one more column from `idaresults` table? Let's say I am using the second method.

Comment: Yes, you would use the second query and add the other column to your subquery's  select list: `max(othercolumn) keep (dense_rank last order by created_timestamp) as othercolumn`. You would not use the first query, because there you would have to add a whole subquery.

Comment: The only problem with two KEEP DENSE RANK is when there can be a tie, i.e. two records for the same latest datetime. Then it can happen that you pick one value from one record and the other from another. You can prevent this by adding `, rowid` to the order by clause: `max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by created_timestamp, rowid) as id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query

```
SELECT 
    MYSCHEME.C.ID as CELLID, 
    MYSCHEME.C.NUM as CELLNUM, 
    MYSCHEME.C.UND_ID as U_ID, 
    MYSCHEME.U.SERIAL as SERIAL, 
    MYSCHEME.U.AMS_NETID as AMSID,
    MYSCHEME.U.IP_ADDRESS as IP_ADDRESS,
    MYSCHEME.U.MAC_ADDRESS as MAC_ADDRESS,
    (select top 1 MYSCHEME.IDARESULTS.ID from MYSCHEME.IDARESULTS where MYSCHEME.C.ID = MYSCHEME.IDARESULTS.CELLID ) as IDAID
    FROM 
    MYSCHEME.C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MYSCHEME.U ON MYSCHEME.C.U_ID = MYSCHEME.U.ID 
    WHERE 
    MYSCHEME.C.SA = 1 AND
    MYSCHEME.U.ID IS NOT NULL;
```